# comparing two files and removing duplicate numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

So I have two different txt files which contain phone numbers. So file1.txt has the following values :

07588787878
07566235245
07577930547
07577930549
07577985858

file2.txt has the following numbers :

07588787878
07566235245
07577930547
07577930590
07577985859

I want to be able to compare my old file which is file1.txt with the new file that is file2.txt and remove the duplicates that exists in file2.txt. I have tried the following but it does not seems to be working for as it's not going through all the values

```
def find_duplicates():
    list1 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to clean!\n")
    list2 = raw_input("Enter name of .txt-file to exclude!\n")
    file1 = read_file(list1)
    file2 = read_file(list2)
    file3 = open('new_file.txt', 'w')

    for line in file1:
        if line not in file2:
            file3.write(str(line) + '\n')  # writes to a new file

    file3.close()
    print('completed')
```

Comment: You are comparing the entire line and not individual numbers. is that the intention ?

Comment: Yes the intention is to compare individual numbers @AajKaal

Comment: Are you sure each number is a line in the file1 and file2?
If a line has multiple numbers try to use file1.split(" ") this will return a list of elements

Comment: yes each number is on a line in file 1 and file2. Could you post a solution so i can understand what you are trying to explain @octopus

Comment: Both the files have same number of lines ? and you want to compare line 1 of both files and then line 2 of both files ?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the phone numbers into two lists and compare them using highly-efficient `set()` function:

```
def Diff(li1, li2):
    return (list(set(li2)-set(li1)))
 
li1 = ['07588787878', '07566235245', '07577930547', '07577930549', '07577985858']
li2 = ['07588787878', '07566235245', '07577930547', '07577930590', '07577985859']
print(Diff(li1, li2))
```

I don't know how your how your text files are structured but if they contains like shown above than this function should do it:

```
def readIntoList(path):
    with open(path, "r") as text1:
        lines = text1.readlines()
        result = []
        for l in lines:
            l_list = l.replace("\n", "").split(" ")
            result.extend(l_list)

    return result
```

Comment: I want to be able to the txt files and then read the numbers in to a list

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r") 
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r") 

file1_raw = f1.read()
file2_raw = f2.read()

file1_words = file1_raw.split()
file2_words = file2_raw.split()
```

if you want unique numbers from file1 that aren't in file2:

```
result = set(file1_words).difference(set(file2_words))
```

if you want the duplicates numbers :

```
result = [x for x in file1_words if x in file2_words]
```

If you care about removing duplicates from file2 :

```
result = [x for x in file2_words if x not in file1_words]

f = open("file2.txt", "w")
f.write(str(result))
```